# How to convert Spannable String into Html formatted String in Android?

Tags: android

I have a spannable string containing bold italics and underlined text ( it may contain more formatted text )
For Example : - abcdef **dfdfdfdf** *dfgdfgfdgf* ***dfgfdgdfgfdfgd***

I want to convert this string into html formatted text such that, my final output contains tags such that the above string should become

abcdef **dfdfdfdf** *dfgdfgfdgf **dfgfdgdfgfdfgd***

```
TextUtils.htmlEncode
```

is not working.
Real World Scenario - You view a webpage and when you view its source it contains tags. Similar thing i want here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `Html.toHtml()` to convert your `Spanned` text into **HTML** string.

```
String htmlString = Html.toHtml(spannedText);
```

Comment: If i use this, then if i have **dfd** in my spannable string, then the html is returned as `<b>d</b><b>f</b><b>d</b>`. I want that it should return <b>dfd</b>. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: i think that's totally up to how the `Html.toHtml` method does the conversion. However what you may do is to use `htmlString.replace("</b><b>", "");` to simplify the tags. Its a hack but will resolve this particular issue.

Comment: Ya did this only. Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 6):

this is how to convert string to html but consider not all html tags working on android .

```
Spanned htmlText = Html.fromHtml(text);
mytextView.setText(htmlText);
```

android supported only this html tags

```
<a href="...">
<b>
<big>
<blockquote>
<br>
<cite>
<dfn>
<div align="...">
<em>
<font size="..." color="..." face="...">
<h1>
<h2>
<h3>
<h4>
<h5>
<h6>
<i>
<img src="...">
<p>
<small>
<strike>
<strong>
<sub>
<sup>
<tt>
<u>
```

Comment: It seams that other tag work to such as &gt; and &lt; for > and <. And there is a bug as < is interpreted as a start tag and not as a lower than sign. see  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58718421/android-how-to-espape-a-greater-than-sign-in-html-fromhtml-which-is-unders/58718627#58718627

Comment: "Too many characters in character literal" error