# Android : How to espape a 'greater than sign' in Html.fromHtml() which is understood as start tag instead of greater than sign

Tags: android, html, spannablestringbuilder

I have a problem with Html.fromHtml which interprets "<" as a start tag and not as a "greater than" sign.

Is there a way to escape the "<" sign so it is displayed ?

Ex :

```
Html.fromHtml("<b>Test</b> : 10", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

Gives **Test** : 10

```
Html.fromHtml("<b>Test</b> : >10", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

Gives **Test** : >10

but

```
Html.fromHtml("<b>Test</b> : <10", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

Gives **Test** :

Comment: Use `&lt;` instead of `<`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use **`&lt;`** to show **<** using Html.

```
Html.fromHtml("<b>Test</b> : &lt;10", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY)
```

Comment: Thank you. This was not referenced as a supported tag but it seams to work well.

Comment: You are welcome @Nathalie. Also press upvote so that others can find it helpful.